# Did Ruby ever support this?

Tags: ruby, hash, syntax

When we define a dict/hash in Ruby, we do like this:

```
{:a => 'b'}
```

But I read some Ruby code like this:

```
{:a : 'b'}
```

This should be Python-like. Did any Ruby version support that? I didn't ever read any Ruby book mentioned that.

Update:

I ran the following command on a Linux box:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
$ ruby -e 'puts {a: "b"}'
-e:1: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
puts {a: "b"}
        ^
```

And ran the following on my Macbook:

```
$ /Users/chaol/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
$ /Users/chaol/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ruby -e 'puts {a: "b"}'
-e:1: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
puts {a: "b"}
        ^
```

Both Ruby version are 1.9+, why do I still get the error?

Comment: Short answer is No. Ruby never supported the second syntax. Could you provide a link to the resource where you read this?

Comment: Try `ruby -e 'puts({a: "b"})'` (note the `(...)`). In your example the `{...}` is being parsed as a block being passed to `puts` rather than the hash.

Answer (score 5):

The correct syntax in the second example is:

```
{ a: 'b' }
```

This is a new feature of Ruby 1.9 and beyond, allowing for a JSON-ish syntax to be used for Ruby hashes.

Comment: It should be noted that Numeric keys can not be used directly in this fashion.

Comment: only symbol keys can be used in this fashion.

Comment: I "rvm install 2.0.0" on my macbook pro, but the code <code>{a: 'b'}</code> still  fail. By the way, how to mark code block in comment?

Comment: Ensure that you're really using the RVM supplied Ruby (`which ruby` should include '.rvm'). You can mark code using backticks. For more information, check out the [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) guide.

Comment: @RyanBigg I issued command `/Users/chaol/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ruby -e 'puts {a: "b"}'` and get error `-e:1: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'`.

Comment: @EvanLi: In that syntax, Ruby can't know if that's supposed to be a block that you're passing to `puts` or if it's a hash. It assumes a block, because that makes the most sense. You should use `puts({a: "b"  })` if you want it to work.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not supported in Ruby, but this similar syntax is supported since Ruby 1.9

```
h = { a: 'b' }
#=> {:a=>"b"}
```

it's equivalent to

```
h = { :a => 'b' }
#=> {:a=>"b"}
```

Comment: @EvanLi That's not related to this style of hash syntax, as it will result error for the more traditional hash syntax as well, try what matt suggests.